# Creating Custom Ajax helper method in MVC 3 stuck

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

So far I have tried creating a Ajax helper method for my Pager in my partial view. It does not work as expected. I have:

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult Test(string page)
{
   var itemsToShow = x => x.Name.StartsWith(page, true, null);
   ViewData["vPage"] = page ?? string.Empty;
   return PartialView(itemsToShow.ToList());
}
```

Currently when I click on a pager item it does nothing, what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your code:

1. In your helper extension '`The name 'letter' does not exist in the current context`'
2. In your controller '`assign lambda expression to an implicitly-typed local variable`'

You would need to fix the above first in order for your project to compile.

Comment: Yes I know of the errors but I need help on the main problem which is to make the ajax helper method work

Comment: If your code doesn't compile, it is difficult to even begin to fix the problem you outline. When you get the above fixed, let me know and I will take another look for you.